# Does the following set spans the real vector space $\mathbb{C} $

Tags: linear-algebra

Does the set $\beta = \{2i-1,2i+3,4 \} $ spans the real vector space $\mathbb{C} $ ?

What I have done:

$span(2i-1,2i+3,4) = \mathbb{C} $

Let $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R}$ then

$a(2i-1)+b(2i+3)+4c = d+ie$

$-a+3b+ 4c + (2a+2b)i = d+ie $

$\implies$ $-a+3b+ 4c =d $ and  $2a+2b = e $

Which gives

$b = \dfrac{e}{2} - a$ and  $c = \dfrac{d}{4} + a - \dfrac{(3 e)}{8}$

As $b,c$ are dependent on $a$ as well. So, $span(2i-1,2i+3,4) \neq \mathbb{C} $

Is this solution correct ?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Doesnt this gives us same system of linear equations as I wrote above?

Comment: @JalilAhmad Presumably it is so you can turn it into a matrix system, and apply the usual Gaussian elimination procedures. However, I think not doing this is better, not because it's simpler, but because in my experience, students who turn everything into matrices automatically tend to miss the finer points of linear algebra (like someone who reaches for a calculator to do every piece of arithmetic).

Comment: By the way, what are $x$ and $y$? You have $a, b, c, d, e$, but nothing about $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @TheoBendit That was a mistake. I have edited the question.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working is good, up until the final line, where you draw a false conclusion. Dependence on $a$ signifies that the solution is not unique, not that there are no solutions. It just means that $a$ can be chosen arbitrarily, while $b$ and $c$ depend on the choice of $a$.

For example, we could make the executive decision that $a = 0$. From this arbitrary choice, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
b &= \frac{e}{2} \\
c &= \frac{d}{4} - \frac{3e}{8}.
\end{align*}
This gives us a linear combination of the three vectors to produce our arbitrary vector $d + ei$. Thus, every $d + ei$ lies in the span of our three vectors.

What the infinitely many choices implies is that the set of vectors is not linearly independent. This is to be expected: we have a two-dimensional space, so any three vector set must be linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank you sir...

Comment: @JalilAhmad 
This is a good answer, so I voted it up. What about you?

Comment: @Hanno Indeed it is.